# Why `bind -x '"$(tput kf5)":"pkill ffplay"'` take as same effect as `bind -x '"\e[15~":"pkill ffplay"'`?

Tags: bash, libreadline

`bind` command can bind a key sequence to a Readline function or a macro.The key sequence of `f5` is `\e[15~`,i bind `f5` with `pkill`.

```
ffplay  movie.mp4
bind -x '"\e[15~":"pkill ffplay"'
```

Now press `f5`, the movie stop playing.

The expression $(command) stands for command substitution; it means run command and put its output here.

```
echo "it is time to dig '\$(tput kf5)' on $(date)."
it is time to dig '$(tput kf5)' on Sat 07 May 2022 09:50:07 PM HKT.
```

Show result of `$(tput kf5)`:

```
debian@debian:~$  echo "$(tput kf5)"

debian@debian:~$  echo '$(tput kf5)'
$(tput kf5)
```

No `\e[15~` output here.Why `bind -x '"$(tput kf5)":"pkill ffplay"'`  take as same effect as `bind -x '"\e[15~":"pkill ffplay"'`?

Comment: You have a typo, should be `tput`.

Comment: Removed the "bind" tag because the bind keyword is predominantly used with non-bash meanings, added libreadline (as bind tells bash to configure the readline library).

Comment: As for the question, though, `fput` isn't a command that exists. Where did you see documentation that says it was what you should use? As Phillipe says, the standard command for looking up terminal control sequences is `tput`.

Comment: (and the edit that says you get `tput: command not found` on Debian is frankly hard to believe, unless you've done something like corrupting your PATH and can't successfully run _any_ external commands).

Comment: ...according to https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ncurses-bin, tput is part of the Debian packages `ncurses-bin`. That should be installed by default out-of-the-box, but if you're running a cut-down / minimal instance of the distro, make sure you have it installed.

Comment: I fix the typo,issue related to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114694/how-can-kill-all-the-processes-triggered-by-hotkey-with-some-smart-way`.

Comment: As for not seeing `\e[15~` when you look at the output of `tput` with `echo`, you're using the wrong tool. `tput` doesn't need to emit a `\e` sequence when it can spit out a literal escape character; pipe its output to `cat -A` or `od -c` or `hexdump` or another tool that can show you nonprintable characters and you'll see a literal escape, not a `\e` sequence meant to be turned into a literal escape later.

Comment: ...also, the behavior of `echo` is very poorly defined, so even if it _was_ a literal escape sequence, echo wouldn't necessarily print it (even if the shell is known to be bash, echo has several modes). See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, the POSIX specification for `echo`, which itself recommends using `printf` instead whenever the input contains backslashes (among other circumstances). For a more extensive discussion, see see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se].

Comment: (if you're curious as to what I mean when I say "echo has several modes" even in bash, look into how the `xpg_echo` runtime flag -- which can also be set at compile time -- modifies `echo`'s behavior, and how it interacts with `set -o posix`; there are a lot of different, mutually-incompatible behaviors one can get out of such a simple-looking command).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$(tput kf5)" | cat -A
^[[15~$
```

Comment: Just `tput kf5 | cat -A` is shorter / more efficient and avoids `echo`'s many pitfalls.